Is it possible to open the phase forward scanned image of the amplitude scanned image, from the .nid file, in Gwyddion software?
I can see all the scan images(amplitude forward, amplitude backward, phase forward, backward, z axis scan forward and backward in the immediate dialogue box  when I choose the file in the software( file browse section) of the .nid file. But, while opening, the amplitude scanned image is only getting opened, cannot able to choose the phase-forward of the same, even if it is in the dropdown menu. This problem is not there with the phase scanned image. In short, the first displayed mode is only displayed, even if all others are present in the file. Can we choose the desired mode from dropdown, or any settings change to be done? I am using Gwyddion 64 bit for windows.
The meta option is not there, which I found in some videos in youtube, to change the displayed mode.
